# How to make a toggler to translate a site using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been working for the past two days on a task which is adding the capability to translate a whole website from English to Spanish when the user selects the toggle button, However, I'm really new into Redux (use it once on a completely different project). The people who gave me the code already configured the reducers, I just need to read the status on each component.

I've tried using this code on one of the components:

```
    const store = createStore(reducer);
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'TOGGLE-LANG'
    });
    store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
```

However, it is still has something missing, and at this point, I'm completely lost and I would love to have some guidance to know what to do.

I created a Gist with all the code involved in this task, It has commented on what's the expected behavior

[Gist Link] : https://gist.github.com/ManudeQuevedo/12cd63cf7431b5ec9b982a37391b7c56

Currently, there are no errors, it is recognizing the reducer (Lang), but I would love to know how to make it actionable in the other components that need to be translated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [i18n](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next). Replacing the text contents on your website to keys, and adding a map matching the keys to different languages.

For example, before you have

```
<div>
  name:
</div>
```

Now it will be like:

```
<div>
 {t('name')}
</div>
```

Here is the link of an [example project](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/v9.x.x/react)

Comment: Thanks, Alex, although your answer is the most accurate one, they configured the redux in a way that made impossible to use this approach. I ended up using another one which I will list below. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question man I appreciated it

Comment: @ManuDeQuevedo No problem. Glad it's helpful:D

Answer (score 0):

At the end this is what I did:

lang.js (reducer)

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initState = fromJS({
  value: 'en',
  translations: {
    en: {
      component: {
        title: 'Mobile Connectivity',
        subtitle: 'Smart Messaging'
      }
    },
    es: {
      component: {
        title: 'Conectividad Móvil',
        subtitle: 'Mensajería Inteligente'
      }
    },
  }
});

export default (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CHANGE_LANGUAGE":
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and I implemented it by destructuring it on this component like so:

```
[Gist][1]
```

I added it to a gist because it's a long code so it would be more readable like that.